# Finding MAX value for two different time ranges in one day PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

so, the way I'm logging production counts in my application is broken into day shift (7AM to 7PM) and night shift (7PM to 7AM). I'm trying to get the total production counts in a given day - so day shift + night shift, but am really struggling on how to do return that result in a query. If I just use MAX(counts) grouped by date, then I only get back the max from one of the shifts. Is there a way to do like a MAX(7AM to 7PM) + MAX(7PM to 7AM) and make that it's own column? I've made two separate queries to get those values, but it would be a lot easier to work with if I had the sum returned in one result. Thanks in advance for any help. New to SQL to apologies if my syntax is terrible

Tried using a UNION to join the two queries which kind of works, but still gives two values per day when I really just want one combined value:

```
SELECT
DATE(t_stamp) as t_stamp, 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Units") as "Day Ongrade Units" ,
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Downgrade_Units") as "Day Downgrade Units", 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Panels") as "Day Ongrade Panels", 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Downgrade_Panels") as "Day Downgrade Panels", 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Panels") + MAX("Stacker_8ft_Downgrade_Panels") as "Day Total Panels" 
FROM eight_ft_stacker_counts where "Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Panels" > 0 and (extract(HOUR FROM t_stamp) > 07 and extract(HOUR FROM t_stamp) < 19) and t_stamp >'2023-07-11 00:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)

UNION

SELECT
DATE(t_stamp) as t_stamp, 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Units") as "Night Ongrade Units" ,
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Downgrade_Units") as "Night Downgrade Units", 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Panels") as "Night Ongrade Panels", 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Downgrade_Panels") as "Night Downgrade Panels", 
MAX("Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Panels") + MAX("Stacker_8ft_Downgrade_Panels") as "Night Total Panels" 
FROM eight_ft_stacker_counts where "Stacker_8ft_Ongrade_Panels" > 0 and (extract(HOUR FROM t_stamp) > 19 or extract(HOUR FROM t_stamp) < 07) and t_stamp >'2023-07-11 00:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(t_stamp)
order by DATE(t_stamp)
```

Which resulted in the graph attached.[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVjmd.png)

Comment: Use `FILTER` in your aggregations:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#:~:text=If%20FILTER%20is%20specified%2C%20then%20only%20the%20input%20rows%20for%20which%20the%20filter_clause%20evaluates%20to%20true%20are%20fed%20to%20the%20aggregate%20function%3B%20other%20rows%20are%20discarded.%20For%20example

Comment: You are a LIFESAVER thanks! So simple, I looked for ages for this and all I found was that you couldn't have more than one WHERE statement in a query but this is exactly what I needed.